# Displaying a large table with an AsyncTask

Tags: android

I have a method that takes data in a very large array and displays a very large table on the Display.  The table is so large that the screen goes blank for awhile.  Can I put the display method inside an Asynctask and display a progress bar until the display method is complete?

Comment: Can you post your code for displaying? Are you using ListView?

Comment: Have no access to my code right now but, no I am not using ListView.  I am using tableView.  Maybe I need to use a lazy display with the scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access Views from background. You can load data into array in a background thread (so it won't block UI during load) and then use this array in an adapter for ListView. I can answer you with more details if you post your code

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Chaosit you can't access the UI from a background thread.

consider loading the data in an async task, for loading the table to the UI try to render it row by row. if you are using a listView there are techniques to add/edit cells without rendering the whole table .

i used the same techniques  when dealing with large number of PINs that needed to be rendered as the user move the Map .i load some of them and render them 1 by 1 to the UI .

Answer (score 0):

The best way to load a big volume of data is to show a `ProgressBar` in `onPreExecute()`, load your data in `doInBackground(...)` and set the visibility of the progress bar to `GONE` in `onPostExecute(Boolean success)`.

Another nice way to do it is display a `Dialog` calling `.show()` in `onPreExecute()` and dismiss it in `onPostExecute(Boolean success)`, maybe updating the Dialog message in the `onProgressUpdate(String... message)`.

Just remember that you cannot update or change your UI in `doInBackground(...)`, but you can in `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute(Boolean success)` and in `onProgressUpdate(String... message)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is coming from a the database (or from a remote source) then consider using Loaders/CursorAdapter - to build your ListView. This is a very efficient way of loading data.

If you're reading Array data from a file then try to break down the data - and just select the data that you're displaying on the screen, rather than reading all the data from the file, and try to render item that will not be displayed - Then you can use AsyncTask or a Thread(and Handler) to update your table.

As the others have mentioned, only the main thread can update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Surely not all the data is shown at once!
Have a look at the [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) guide. It will allow you to load a large data set, and display only part of it, reducing load times.

Answer (score 0):

Said functionality can be achieved using asynctask as

```
class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
{    
  protected void onPreExecute ()
  {
    //Start showing progress bar here ...
  }

  protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) 
   {
    // Do long running operation here ...

    return "You are at PostExecute";
   }

  protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
  {
    // Start displaying data in your table view and dismiss the progress  bar 
  }
}
```

Call it like this in your activity:

```
new TestAsync().execute();
```